# $Tv$ is not a Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Is the Following Proof Correct?

*Theorem.* Given that $U$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $U\neq V$ and that $S\in\mathcal{L}(U,W)$ and $S\neq 0$. Define $T:V\to W$
$$
Tv=
\begin{cases}
Sv ,v\in U\\
0,v\in V\backslash U
\end{cases}
$$
Show that $Tv$ is not a linear map.

*Proof.* Assume for purpose of contradiction that $Tv$ as defined above is a linear map.

Since $U\neq V$ and $U\leqslant V$, there exists a $v\neq 0\in V\backslash U$ consequently $T(v)=0$
moreover as $S\neq 0$ it follows that for some $u\in U$, $S(u)=w\neq 0$ evidently the vector $u+v\in V\backslash U$ implying that $T(v+u)=0$ but the *additivity* of $T$ implies that 
$T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)=w+0=w\neq 0$ resulting in a contradiction.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I do have some reservations over the statement $u+v\in V\backslash U$ although it seems pretty obvious

Comment: Suppose otherwise: $u+v\in U$. But $u\in U$ and from additivity $v=(u+v)-u$ so  $v\in U$ - contradiction.

Comment: @Przemek Thanks Now I can relax !

Comment: Maybe is just me, but I dislike the notation $v\neq 0\in V\setminus U$. I think it's better to write $v\in V\setminus U$, $v\neq 0$.

Comment: Now that i think about it is quite ugly !